# Python - Generate list of lists from other list values

Tags: python-3.x, generator

I need to generate a list of lists in that special way:

```
[3, 1, 4] -> [[1, 2, 3], [1], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

That means that every list in a list of lists must be in range of the given list values. I've tried smth like:

```
L = [3, 1, 4]
q = [i for i in L]
print(list([x] for x in range(y for y in q)))
```

But it return a TypeError: generator cannot be interpreted as an integer

That all has to be a single generator expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a `list comprehension`.

Try:

```
L = [3, 1, 4]
print([list(range(1, i+1)) for i in L])
```

**Output:**

```
[[1, 2, 3], [1], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

Comment: That works! Thank you a lot. Could you please explain me the construction of list(range())? (Just a little bit)

Comment: In python3 `range`  is a generator. that is why I am encapsulating it in `list`. if I do not do that you will get a generator expression